# how to store the image immediately after reading it in a for loop?

Tags: image, matlab

I tried the following program for reading multiple images(about 300 images). Now I want to store these images immediately after reading each to some location by some name as `g1`,`g2`,`g3`... Is it possible to do this in a loop?
Here is my attempt:

```
for i=1:5
    m=imread(['C:\Users\shree\Desktop\1\im' num2str(i) '.jpg']);
    figure,imshow(m);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you store them in a cell array:

```
for k=1:5
    image_path = ['C:\Users\shree\Desktop\1\im' num2str(i) '.jpg']; %// I have moved this to be on its own line as it will make debugging easier. You don't have to, but I think it's a good idea.
    images_all{k}  = imread(image_path);
end
```

By using `eval` to create variable names like `g1`, `g2` etc you pollute your workspace with an unmanageable amount of variables. Plus if they are all in a cell array then it's really easy to apply the same function to each of them either in a loop or with `cellfun`.

For example if you want to convert them all to greyscale now:

```
images_grey = cellfun(@rgb2gray, images_all, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Also, you can store images of different sizes. It cannot be done if you are using a 4-D matrix.

Comment: hey thanks, i modified my code accordingly, now i am again stucked :( i want to resize all of these grayscale images and store these resized images with some names as r1,r2...how can i do this..please do help me...

Comment: @arch Can you provide some code demonstrating how you resize one image please

Comment: i am using imresize(img,[50 50]);

Comment: @arch then it's as simple as applying it in a loop or `images_resized = cellfun(@(x)(imresize(x, [50, 50]), images_all)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
for i=1:5
    img =imread(['C:\Users\shree\Desktop\1\im' num2str(i) '.jpg']);
    evalc(['g' num2str(i) '=img;']);
end
figure,imshow(g1);
figure,imshow(g2);
```

Another approach could be to use [STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/struct.h) and store those images as fields of a struct.

Storing as a 4D matrix is another efficient way as suggested by herohuyongtao.

Comment: heyy thanks,its working but i cannot to access these images for ex.if i want to read g1 again then how can i do this???

Comment: Later on inside the code you can access g1,g2,g3..etc. So, after the loop ends, try imshow(g1);. Edited my code accordingly.

Comment: can you please tell me how should i convert all these images g1,g2....to gray scale..should i give rgb2gray command inside the loop or should i write another loop for same

Comment: Use - "evalc(['g' num2str(i) '=rgb2gray(img);']);" instead of "evalc(['g' num2str(i) '=img;']);".

Comment: I must recommend against using `eval`\`evalc` here. The struct approach is a much better idea. You don't want to end up with 300 differently named variables since you're almost definitely planning some more processing on them Rather keep them in a collection like a struct, or even better in my opinion would be a cell array. Not to mention that using `eval` can be a nightmare to debug.

Comment: Good tips Dan! Fully agreed. With 5 or so images though, it could be just fine I think.

Comment: hey i modified my code accordingly, now i am again stucked :( i want to resize all of these grayscale images and store these resized images with some names as r1,r2...how can i do this..please do help me...

Comment: But the OP mentions over 300 images... and even with 5 I would say it's bad practice to use `eval` when not absolutely necessary

Comment: @arch. Try this - "for i=1:5
    reshaped_img = imresize(g1,your_params);
    evalc(['r' num2str(i) '=reshaped_img;']);
end". Also, look at Dan's cell approach, it's better for a series of images.

Comment: its working fine but if i tried to show g45 and r45 i.e. gray and resized image at a time its showing two different images instead of showing two  different copies of same original image .. for referance here is the code :  for i=1:50
    img =imread(['C:\Users\shree\Desktop\final data\target\' num2str(i) '.jpg']);
        reshaped_img = imresize(g1,[50 50]);
    evalc(['r' num2str(i) '=reshaped_img;']);
    
end
figure,imshow(g45);figure,imshow(r45);       why is it so?? (jst fyi,i am working on facial images of different people)

Comment: This is going crazy with the variable names, but still to finish up on resizing, try this - "for i=1:5
    var1 = ['g' num2str(i)];
    evalc(['img1 = ' var1]);
    reshaped_img = imresize(img1,[50 50]);
    evalc(['r' num2str(i) '=reshaped_img;']);
end"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save all them into one big matrix:

```
for i=1:5  
    images_all(:, :, :, i)  = imread(['C:\Users\shree\Desktop\1\im' num2str(i) '.jpg'])
end
```

After this, all images will be stored in `images_all` (here assume that all images are colored images, i.e. 3 channels).

Comment: i tried this but it is showing following error,Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> p1 at 16
    images_all(:, :, :, i)  = imread(['C:\Users\shree\Desktop\1\im' num2str(i)
    '.jpg'])

Comment: @user3387228 Are your images grayscale?